# How to make casperJS wait until .change() event is finished?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am triggering a change event in my casperJS script which triggers an AJAX request like such:

```
casper.evaluate(function(i) {
    $("form:eq(2) select option:eq(" + i + ")").attr("selected", "selected").change();
},i);
```

How can I make casperJS wait until the underlying AJAX request has been finished? Already tried to look at the [docs](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) but I am more or less stuck. Can anyone guide me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this in a static way using `casper.wait`.

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(i) {
    // change()
},i).wait(5000).then(function(){
    // further processing
});
```

And hope that the request is done in 5 seconds, but maybe you lose some time waiting when the request is done much sooner than 5 seconds. The problem is that as soon as the request is finished doesn't mean that the page is ready/changed.

Another possibility would be to wait for the request to finish, but for this to work you will need to register for the success event of the request somehow. Most of the time you don't have access to this from the global scope. If you do then you can use

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(i) {
    window._someUniqueVariable = false;
    registerSuccessEvent(function(data){
        window._someUniqueVariable = true;
    });
},i).waitFor(function check(){
    return this.evaluate(function(){
        window._someUniqueVariable = true;
    });
}, function(){
    // further processing
});
```

A more Casper-way of doing that would be to use `casper.waitForResource`, but then you would need to know the url beforehand or at least able to deduce it from the page.

In the general case, when the request comes back it does something to your page. So you should be able to `waitForSelector` with a new element or `waitForSelectorTextChange` or `waitUntilVisible` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you probably missed **waitForResource**

from the docs: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource

```
casper.waitForResource("you url here", function()
{
     // place your code here
});
```